Locus of 4 colinear points in $\mathbb{P}^2$
I'm trying to solve exercises 2.34 and 2.35 in 3264 and all that (Eisenbud & Harris, 2016, p.80).

Exercice 2.34
Let $\varphi\subset(\mathbb{P}^2)^4$ be the locus of 4-tuples of colinear points. Find its class by the method of undetermined coefficients.

My solution :

$[\varphi]$ lies in $A^2((\mathbb{P}^2)^4)$ because the projection on the first two factors is onto and the fiber over $(p,q)\in (\mathbb{P^2})^2$  is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1$ (when $p\neq q$).

$A((\mathbb{P}^2)^4)=\mathbb{Z}[\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta]/(\alpha^3,\beta^3,\gamma^3,\delta^3)$.

Therefore $\displaystyle[\varphi]=\sum_{0\le i,j,k,l\le 2\\ i+j+k+l=2}c_{ijkl}\alpha^i\beta^j\gamma^k\delta^l$ for some undetermined coefficients $(c_{i,j,k,l})$.

By symmetry, the coefficients $c_{ijkl}$ are symmetric in $(ijkl)$, so we only need to compute $c_{2,0,0,0}$ and $c_{1,1,0,0}$

$c_{2,0,0,0}=\deg([\varphi].\beta^2\gamma^2\delta^2) = card(\varphi \cap (\mathbb{P}^2\times F\times G\times H))$ where $F$, $G$, $H$ are linear subspaces of codimension $2$ -- that is: points.
But that means $c_{2,0,0,0}=0$ because three general points are not aligned in $\mathbb{P}^2$.

$c_{1,1,0,0}=\deg([\varphi].\alpha\beta\gamma^2\delta^2) = card(\varphi \cap (E\times F\times G\times H))$ where $E$ and $F$ are linear subspaces of codimension $1$ (that is, lines) and $G$ and $H$ are linear subspaces of codimension $2$ (that is, points).
But then $c_{1,1,0,0}=1$ because both $E$ and $F$ meet the line GH in one point each.

Conclusion : $[\varphi]=\alpha\beta+\alpha\gamma+\alpha\delta+ \beta\gamma+\beta\delta+\gamma\delta$.



Exercice 2.35
Calculate the class $[\varphi]$ (same $\varphi$ as above) by using the result of exercise 2.32 on the locus of $\psi\subset(\mathbb{P}^2)^3$ of triples of colinear points and considering the intersection of the loci $\psi_{1,2,3}$ and $\psi_{1,2,4}$ of $4$-tuples $(p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4)$ with  $(p_1,p_2,p_3)$ and $(p_1,p_2,p_4)$ colinear each.

My solution :

In exercise 2.32, I found that the class $[\phi]\in A^{n-1}(\mathbb{P}^n\times \mathbb{P}^n\times \mathbb{P}^n)$ of the locus of triples of colinear points was $$\displaystyle [\phi]=\sum_{0\le i,j,k\le n-1\\ i+j+k=n-1 } \alpha^i\beta^j\gamma^k$$

For $n=2$, i find that $[\psi_{1,2,3}]=\alpha+\beta+\gamma$ and $[\psi_{1,2,4}]=\alpha+\beta+\delta$.

From $\varphi =\psi_{1,2,3}\cap \psi_{1,2,4}$, we get $[\varphi]=(\alpha+\beta+\gamma).(\alpha+\beta+\delta)$ ?


That doesn't seem right. For one thing, that's not the same result i found in the previous exercise. For another thing, it's not symmetric in $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ which is odd.
Questions :

Is my solution to exercise 2.34 correct ? (I mean, both the result and the proof.)

Where's my mistake in 2.35 ? How to fix it ?



The intersection $\psi_{1,2,3} \cap \psi_{1,2,4}$ has an extra codim-$2$ component: $\{p_1 = p_2\}$. So you need to subtract the diagonal class supported on those coordinates, ie $\alpha^2 + \alpha \beta + \beta^2$. Everything else looks right to me.

Thanks ! It seems so obvious now.
